# How to add icons to APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to add png files as icons to APEX. I have a report and one column should be my specific icon.I've tried to add image url to link label but it was not worked.
Is there way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way by trying.
Go Application #xx -> Shared Components -> Under the Files region "Images"
There are several icons there and you may add new icons by creating.
Click Create and choose which application will use this icon,upload image.
Now go report item and copy the following text :

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/managing-static-application-files.html#GUID-A580AAF3-D89A-440F-B75D-5A68DCB6BBF5